# TFS 2013 Report error

Tags: tfs, ssas, reporting-services-2012

We have a  whole bunch of reports sitting in TFS 2010, then we decide to directly upgrade to TFS 2013. 
Upgrading and configuration and have been done successfully.
However those old reports are not working, I fixed the data source connection string and rebuild the data warehouse successfully.
But I get the error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'IterationParam'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
>   The dimension '[Iteration]' was not found in the cube when the string, [Iteration].[Parent_ID].[XXX], was parsed.

I looked in the analysis service database and could not find `Itration Dimension`.
Is something wrong? Please give me advice
cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Did you rebuild just the warehouse, or the cube also?  You need to do both.  And you need to rebuild the warehouse first, then the cube afterwards.

I use the TFS Web Services to do this:

- Fire up the web service page, for me its: `http://localhost:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx`
- Execute GetProcessingStatus passing false for the includeOnlineHostsOnly
- Make sure that all the jobs are currently Idle
- Execute ProcessWarehouse leaving the args blank
- Rerun GetProcessingStatus until all the warehouse jobs are idle again
- Execute ProcessAnalysisDatabase passing in Full for the processingType
- Rerun GetProcessingStatus until all the jobs are idle again

Comment: Hi Dylan, yes I did, I have rebuild the whole datawarehouse, rebuild Analysis service(cube), all job status are successful, and updated,